# RIA Services Entity Deletion

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I have a DomainService which I am trying to delete records from.

Assuming the following rough code server-side method:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
{
    DataLoadOptions loadOpts = new DataLoadOptions();
    loadOpts.LoadWith<Models.Employee>(e => e.PhoneNumber);

    this.DataContext.LoadOptions = loadOpts; 
    return this.DataContext.Employees;
}
```

This means that when I load all my employees, all their Phone Numbers are included.

I can do the following client side code, with *phoneNumber* being an entity:

```
domainContext.Employees.PhoneNumbers.Remove(phoneNumber);
```

This, as I understand it, removes the *relationship* between Employee and PhoneNumber entitities, but what I really want is the complete removal of PhoneNumber from the database. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is the relationship between Employee and PhoneNumber 1:1 or 1:M?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `PhoneNumbers` is also an Entity on the Client side, then you can do the following:

```
domainContext.Employees.PhoneNumbers.Remove(phoneNumber); // remove relationship
domainContext.PhoneNumbers.Remove(phoneNumber); // remove entity
```